# Разве obj не объект? objGlobal.obj[ ] из этого кода выходит что obj это массив

Tags: javascript

```js
var objGlobal={
obj: {
array1: [2, 4, 22, 56],
array2: [34, 12, 56, 3]
}
}
console.log(objGlobal.obj[typeOfArray][2]; //typeOfArray равно array1 или array2. Есть такая функция где определяется typeOfArray.
 console.log(objGlobal.obj.array1[3];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Вариант через квадратные скобки
objGlobal.obj['array1'][2]

Вариант через точку
objGlobal.obj.array1[2]
```

Эти две записи идентичные.

Квадратные скобки используют для того чтобы получить доступ к свойству объекта через переменную или в том случае когда ключ числовой или содержит пробел, дефис или другой символ который нельзя использовать через точку.

Данный пример никак не означает что `obj` является массивом. Это просто синтаксис и не более.

Более подробнее можете почитать в статье [Работа с объектами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
 на сайте [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

Также в статье [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) найдете больше информации о доступе к свойствам объекта.

Comment: Спасибо большое, понятно. Я когда-то прочла эти нюансы, но оказывается забыла

Comment: когда учил javascript то это меня тоже сбило с толку